# How to redirect script output to a text file and continue despite log-out

Tags: linux, script

What is the difference between:

```
nohup bin/admin/release.sh > /users/john/release_output 2>&1 &
```

and

```
bin/admin/release.sh > /users/john/release_output &
```

I want to run release.sh and run it in backround (it should continue working even if I close shell window), I also want to save output to release_output in my home directory (/users/john/)

Answer (score 2):

- The trailing `&` runs the process in the background. The important aspect of this is that you get a command prompt back without waiting for the script to finish and can therefore issue a logout command without waiting.
- The `2>&1` ensures that the process doesn't get a "broken pipeline" signal when STDERR's destination (the terminal/tty) is disconnected (but I think `nohup` may take care of that). 
  You could instead redirect STDERR to a separate file if preferred.
- `nohup` ensures the process isn't sent a HUP (hangup) signal when the associated terminal session is closed.

If you read the man page for `nohup` you should see it is designed specifically for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it in background and keep running even user logout then `nohup` is there for you.